# Find all child realm objects where the parent's id is X

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

In this [example](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#many-to-one), the docs talked about getting the parent objects while specifying queries for the child objects.

Is there a way for getting the child objects while specifying a query for the parent object?

In the given example, can I search for dogs who are of brown color with the user named John?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** Since Realm 3.5.0, you can actually use the "backlinks" mentioned in the comment section. Rejoice!

In fact, since Realm 3.0.0, bidirectional links are a performance bottleneck, so using backlinks is the preferred way.

The way it works is:

```
public class User extends RealmObject {
    private RealmList<Dog> dogs;
}

public class Dog extends RealmObject {
    @LinkingObjects("dogs")
    private final RealmResults<User> owners = null;
}
```

Now you can do:

```
realm.where(Dog.class).equalTo("color", "Brown").equalTo("owners.name", "John").findAll();
```

**OLD ANSWER:**

You can only search for **dogs** with a given **user** if you have an object link to the User.

```
public class Dog extends RealmObject {
    //...
    private User user;
}
```

Then you could do

```
realm.where(Dog.class).equalTo("color", "Brown").equalTo("user.name", "John").findAll();
```

Comment: The above is correct. Right now you have to manually maintain that reference, but we have a concept called backlinks on our TODO that will make this much easier to do: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/607

Comment: But it's P2, so it's worth doing it this way for the time being.